# Stop Polymer's iron-form navigating away to the action url

Tags: javascript, polymer

I've implemented a login page via an iron-form and it's working just fine.  However, is it possible to stop the form navigating away to the "action" url?  I have a SPA and want to stay within my routes and therefore I want to stay on the current route.  The docs state that iron-form implements an iron-ajax component so I'm guessing that it should be possible.

For now, I've had to revert to using iron-ajax with a post method to keep me on the same page.

I'm using > 1.0.0 of Polymer.

Comment: Can you post some code? It should be making an AJAX request.

Comment: It does make the request and I get back my JSON - however the form post makes the page navigate away to the form's action url.  So in affect I see an HTML page with the JSON on it.  I just want the form to post but stay where it is and not navigate to the action url.

Comment: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form/pull/31 this suggests there was a problem but it was fixed in July. You know about using the method POST with iron-form I guess?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem in my code, but I just forgot to import the form component. In my case it is: `<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-form/iron-form.html">`
Please check, maybe you have the same bug.